# Redirect an url keeping its queries and adding a fixed one

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect from an url to another url but keeping the queries.
For example, from

```
/oldurl?query1=yes&query2=yes&... (or any list of queries)
```

to

```
/newurl?fixedquery=yes&query1=yes&query2=yes&...
```

So in pratice it would redirect the old url and its queries to a new url, keeping the old queries, plus a fixed query.

This is what I have been trying to use (unsuccessfully) in the .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /oldurl/?$ newurl/?fixedquery=yes&$1
```

I also tried before using Rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^fixedquery=yes$
RewriteRule ^oldurl/?$ newurl/? [R=301,L]
```

But this simply redirects if for `/oldurl` (adding `fixedquery`) and gives a 404 in case I pass a query to oldurl (e.g. `/oldurl?var1=1`).

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use mod_rewrite in order to manipulate the query string. Try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^oldurl/?$ /newurl?fixedquery=yes [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Your example URL omits the trailing slash on the target URL, so I omitted it here. However, in your directives, you are including it?

The `QSA` flag appends/merges the original query string from the request. So the resulting URL is `/newurl?fixedquery=yes&query1=yes&query2=yes&...`, where `query1=yes&query2=yes&...` were passed on the initial request.

**UPDATE:** Note that this rule needs to go near the top of the file, *before* any existing rewrites. The order of directives in the `.htaccess` file can be important. Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues. And you will need to ensure the browser cache is cleared before testing.

---

A look at your attempts...

> ```
> RedirectMatch 301 /oldurl/?$ newurl/?fixedquery=yes&$1
> ```

The `RedirectMatch` (mod_alias) directive matches against the URL-path only, but you have no capturing subgroup in the regex, so the `$1` backreference is always empty.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^fixedquery=yes$
> RewriteRule ^oldurl/?$ newurl/? [R=301,L]
> ```

This *matches* a request for `/oldurl?fixedquery=yes` and redirects to `newurl/` - removing the query string entirely. However, this is also reliant on `RewriteBase` being set, otherwise this will result in a malformed redirect, exposing your directory structure.

Comment: Thank you. I tried RewriteRule, now in private browsing to be sure I am not getting redirected by cache, and with both these rules:

```RewriteRule ^oldurl/?$ /newurl/? [R=301,L]```

and

```RewriteRule ^oldurl/?$ newurl/? [QSA, R=301,L]```

in both cases it gives a 404 on oldurl. Redirect and RedirectMatch both work.
Should I perhaps add something more than RewriteEngine On?

Comment: @Filippo So you are not seeing a redirect at all? (Btw, that 2nd rule is invalid - there should be no space in the flags argument). If you have other mod_rewrite directives then you've likely put this rule in the wrong place. The order is important. This will likely need to go near the top of the `.htaccess` file, _before_ any other rewrites. You should be testing with a 302 (temp) redirect to avoid potential caching issues. "in private browsing" - it needs to be a **new** private browsing session (private browsing still uses a cache).

Comment: @Filippo or... test with the browser dev tools open on the "Network" tab with "Disable cache" checked.

Comment: It was a matter of position. I moved the Rewrite with [QSA, R=301,L] near to the very top of .htaccess and now it works correctly. Thank you very much, you where very clear and helpful.